# How can i vaalidate Google reCaptcha on HTML form submit button

Tags: forms, validation, recaptcha

I have used following form:
`

```
<fieldset>
<div class="zl-form-captcha">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-key" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</div>      
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn">Submit</button></p>
</fieldset>
```

`

How can i validate google captcha form before form submit?

Thanks.

Comment: I have also included `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` script inside`<head></head>` tag.

Comment: That solutions not work for me. So i created my separate questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot validate captcha on the client (browser), so you cannot validate it before submit.

Captcha validation has to be done on the server, after the form is submitted, as it involves calling google with their API to validate that the captcha was answered correctly Refer to this page on how to do this verification: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify.